# Is it possible to simulate/emulate non-euclidean geometry using computer graphics?

Tags: computational-geometry, graphics, euclidean-distance

I am aware of the frequent use of "smoke and mirrors" in order to achieve the effect of non-euclidean geometry, but I was wondering it if it possible to implement spherical (sometimes called elliptic) and hyperbolic geometries.  If so, how would we do that?

Comment: Questions about specific software packages are off-topic here.

Comment: No specific software package should be discussed. Only what theory, algorithms and overall logic should be used in order to implement it.

Comment: Asking about how to do something with a library is off-topic, but asking how to do something is suitable.  That said, I don't understand your question.  It sounds like your first sentence has the form "I am aware of a way to do X using 'smoke and mirrors', but I was wondering if it is possible to do X."  Have you already answered your own question?  Also, can you edit the question  to clarify what you mean by "implement a geometry"?  What operations do you want to support?  And what do you mean by "smoke and mirrors"?